# GROUP BY and array_agg in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a query as follows:

```
WITH "data" ("displayName","habitas","_rowId") AS (VALUES
 ('Moo','[{"id":"1", "name": "A"},{"id":"2", "name": "B"}]'::json,1)
,('Boo','[{"id":"3", "name": "C"},{"id":"2", "name": "B"}]'::json,2))
SELECT
  t.id, "data"."_rowId", t.name
FROM "data"
    CROSS JOIN
    json_to_recordset("data"."habitas") as t("id" text, "name" text)
```

and it returns results as:

```
id  | _rowId | name
1   |1       |  A
2   |1       |  B
3   |2       |  C
2   |2       |  B
```

I actually want the results to be grouped by the id column so I've produced this SQL after some trial and error:

```
WITH "data" ("displayName","habitas","_rowId") AS (VALUES
 ('Moo','[{"id":"1", "name": "A"},{"id":"2", "name": "B"}]'::json,1)
,('Boo','[{"id":"3", "name": "C"},{"id":"2", "name": "B"}]'::json,2))
SELECT
  t.id, array_agg("data"."_rowId"), t.name
FROM "data"
    CROSS JOIN
    json_to_recordset("data"."habitas") as t("id" text, "name" text)
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
```

and this then produces the correct results:

```
id  | _rowId | name
1   |{1}     |  A
2   |{2}     |  C
3   |{1,2}   |  B
```

It's fairly ok looking and seems to work but I'm wondering if I've missed any tricks to construct this query in a better way?

Comment: You've done it in a natural, proper way. `LEFT JOIN ... ON TRUE` looks a bit strange, just `CROSS JOIN` is more readable.

Comment: Thanks @klin - I too like the readability of CROSS JOIN better so have adapted my query accordingly.

Comment: Quoted identifiers are hard to read and can give you problems. Only use it if there are illegal characters in the identifiers. Basically only ORMs will need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few minor points:

- Since you are performing an implicit lateral join between the row source `"data"` and the function `json_to_recordset()` you are effectively not making an unqualified join between two row sources but a join between a row from `"data"` and whichever rows the function produces. The `CROSS JOIN` clause implies an unqualified join and it obscures the fact that this is a lateral join (so I liked your original version better, if the `LEFT` clause is removed). In a case like this I would simply use the good ol' comma `,` list: `FROM "data", json_to_recordset("data"."habitas")`.
- You should use double quotes `"` around identifiers consistently.
- If you want to guarantee that the `"_rowId"` values are in order in the array, then you should use `array_agg("data"."_rowId" ORDER BY "data"."_rowId")`.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's how I found my original solution.  I didn't realise I can just  add it into the FROM clause, that's VERY cool!.  Agree on consistent quoting and the ordering ability is damn handy - thank you again.